# OpenGL shader issue

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glut

I need help with some OpenGL code I am trying to create. Essentially I am trying to create a triangle that is colored green.

Below is the environment, error and code. Can someone please help ?

Env:
 Mac OS: High Sierra
 Video : Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB graphics

Error Message:

> 2018-11-14 20:25:46.416648-0800 GLFW opengl[41517:6223602] MessageTracer: load_domain_whitelist_search_tree:73: Search tree file's format version number (0) is not supported
>   2018-11-14 20:25:46.416773-0800 GLFW opengl[41517:6223602] MessageTracer: Falling back to default whitelist
>   INFO: OpenGL Version: 2.1 INTEL-10.36.19/n
>   ERROR: 0:1: '' :   Invalid Directive: version440
>   ERROR: 0:2: '(' : syntax error: syntax error

code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "glew.h"
#include "freeglut.h" // Include the freeGLUT header file

using namespace std;

#define WINDOW_TITLE "Modern OpenGL"

#ifndef GLSL
#define GLSL(Version, source) "#version" #Version "\n" #source
#endif

int WindowWidth = 800, WindowHeight = 600;

void UInitialize(int,char*[]);
void UInitWindow(int,char*[]);
void UResizeWindow(int,int);
void URenderGraphics(void);
void UCreateVBO(void);
void UCreateShaders(void);

const GLchar * VertexShader = GLSL(440,
    in layout(location=0) vec4 vertex_Postion;
        void main(){
            gl_Postion = vertex_Postion;
        }
);

const GLchar * FragmentShader = GLSL(440,
    void main(){
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    }
);


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    UInitialize(argc, argv);
    glutMainLoop();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void UInitialize(int argc, char* argv[]){
    GLenum GlewInitResult;
    UInitWindow(argc, argv);
    GlewInitResult = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != GlewInitResult) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR:%s/n",glewGetErrorString(GlewInitResult));
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "INFO: OpenGL Version: %s/n",glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    UCreateVBO();
    UCreateShaders();
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}

void UInitWindow(int argc, char* argv[]){

    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutCreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE);
    glutReshapeFunc(UResizeWindow);
    glutDisplayFunc(URenderGraphics);

}

void UResizeWindow(int width, int height){
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
void URenderGraphics(void){

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLuint totalVertices = 3;
    //creates tirangle
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, totalVertices);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
void UCreateVBO(void){
    GLfloat verts[]={
      0.0f,1.0f,
      -1.0f,-1.0f,
        1.0f,-1.0f
    };
    float numVertices = sizeof(verts);
    GLuint myBufferID;
    glGenBuffers(1,&myBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,myBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,numVertices,verts,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GLuint floatsPerVertex = 2;
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0,floatsPerVertex,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);
}

void UCreateShaders(void){
    GLuint ProgramId = glCreateProgram();

    GLuint vertexShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fragmentShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(vertexShaderId,1,&VertexShader,NULL);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShaderId,1,&FragmentShader,NULL);

    glCompileShader(vertexShaderId);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShaderId);

    GLint isCompiled = 0;
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &isCompiled);
    char *infoLog;
    int infologLength = 0;
    int charsWritten  = 0;
    if(isCompiled == GL_FALSE)
    {
        glGetShaderiv(vertexShaderId, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infologLength);

        if (infologLength > 0)
        {
            infoLog = (char *)malloc(infologLength);
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShaderId, infologLength, &charsWritten, infoLog);
            printf("\n%s\n",infoLog);
            free(infoLog);
        }

        // Provide the infolog in whatever manor you deem best.
        // Exit with failure.
        glDeleteShader(vertexShaderId); // Don't leak the shader.
        return;
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "OK!!!!!!!!!");
    glAttachShader(ProgramId,vertexShaderId);
    glAttachShader(ProgramId,fragmentShaderId);

    glLinkProgram(ProgramId);
    glUseProgram(ProgramId);
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use `#version 440` GLSL on a GL 2.1 context?

Answer (score 1):

Read the error message:

> ERROR: 0:1: '' : Invalid Directive: version440
>   ERROR: 0:2: '(' : syntax error: syntax error

this is caused, because the first line in your shader code is:

```
#version440
```

but the correct syntax would be `#version 440`.

This line is automatically generated by the macro `GLSL`. You have to insert a blank at the end of `"#version"`, so it has to be:

```cpp
#ifndef GLSL
#define GLSL(Version, source) "#version " #Version "\n" #source
#endif
```

---

There is a typo in you vertex shader program. It has to be `gl_Position` instead of `gl_Postion`.

You have to check the compilation state of the vertex shader and fragment shader separately:

```
GLint isCompiled = 0;

glCompileShader(vertexShaderId);
glGetShaderiv(vertexShaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &isCompiled);
if ( isCompiled == GL_FALSE )
{
    GLint infologLength;
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShaderId, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infologLength);
    std::vector< char >infoLog(infologLength);
    GLsizei charsWritten;
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShaderId, infologLength, &charsWritten, infoLog.data());
    std::cout << "compile error:" << std::endl << infoLog.data() << std::endl;
    // .....
}

glCompileShader(fragmentShaderId);
glGetShaderiv(fragmentShaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &isCompiled);
if ( isCompiled == GL_FALSE )
{
    GLint infologLength;
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShaderId, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infologLength);
    std::vector< char >infoLog(infologLength);
    GLsizei charsWritten;
    glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShaderId, infologLength, &charsWritten, infoLog.data());
    std::cout << "compile error:" << std::endl << infoLog.data() << std::endl;
    // .....
}
```

Comment: I was able to fix these issues thank you for helping me out but the triangle is still not being shaded green.

Comment: @AkhilSompalli `gl_Position` instead of `gl_Postion`